# VS 2010 Performance Profiler : Identifying Threads

Tags: .net, visual-studio, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have launched a performance wizard in VS2010 to audit thread concurrency in my Application.

Is there a way to identify exactly what specific threads "Worker Threads" point to in my app ?
Indeed, I launch worker threads. Is there a way to name them and/or timestamp same logical thread that is launched many times. (Am I using this right or is it a loony idea ?)

This would allow me to identify threads which cause high Cross-Core context switches and take action (right ? )

[image: Core View]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are creating your threads it is possible to name them

See this [msdn page for details of the Thread.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx) property

Comment: The problem is that I use BackgroundWorkers, as I have a GUI that I do not want to freeze, and I take advantage of the wrap-up of start/stop utilities provided by this class. The problem is that threads created this way are not nameable from what i've read. Besides, I am not 100% sure naming threads at runtime would result in displaying that particular name in this window.